# function check short int algorithm

Tags: c

This is my function and I need help....
I must try to catch the range of `short int` without error handler or try&catch.
I cant´t find my failure in this algorithm — I hope you can help me.

```
short int checkShortInt(char * myString)
{
    short int i = 0;
    short int len;

    if((myString[i]=='+')||(myString[i]=='-')) i++;

    for (len = i; myString[len] != '\0'; len++);

    if(len-i>5) return(0);
    if(myString[i+0]<'3') return(1);
    if(myString[i+0]>'3') return(0);
    if(myString[i+1]<'2') return(1);
    if(myString[i+1]>'2') return(0);
    if(myString[i+2]<'7') return(1);
    if(myString[i+2]>'7') return(0);
    if(myString[i+3]<'6') return(1);
    if(myString[i+3]>'6') return(0);
    if(myString[i+4]>'7') return(0);
    return(1);
}
```

Comment: Provide sample input, and expected output.

Comment: I don't get what do you mean by catch the range of short. Looks like you want to check if some value will fit into short. If so, it's probably one of the ugliest tries you can imagine.

Answer (score 1):

1. Note that the range covered by `short` is asymmetric when two's complement is used: it normally ranges from -32768 to 32767.
2. If the length of the value is smaller than 5, the string clearly fits into a short.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents. Maybe overkill...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int checkShortInt(char *myString)
{
    long long i = strtoll(myString, 0, 0);
    return (i >= SHRT_MIN && i <= SHRT_MAX);
}
```

Comment: +1 Any reason of choosing `strtoll` over `strtol`? I think it also would work.

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk, no reason, strtol would work just as well. I commented on the other answers asking for strtol but no one responded so I wrote my own answer somewhat jokingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
short int checkShortInt(char * myString)
{
    short int i = 0;
    int total = 0;

    // Skip a leading +/- sign.
    if((myString[i]=='+')||(myString[i]=='-')) i++;

    while(myString[i] != '\0')
    {
        total = 10*total + myString[i]-'0';
        ++i;
    }

    if (SHRT_MIN <= total && total <= SHRT_MAX)
    {
        return total;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sample inputs and results:

```
checkShortInt("53") ==> 53
checkShortInt("+125") ==> 125
checkShortInt("0") ==> 0
checkShortInt("70345") ==> 0
```

Comment: Try to enter `"abc"` to see where it goes wrong.

Comment: checkShortInt("0") ==> 0 roh roh

Comment: @abelenky and 0 as a return means FALSE, right..?

Comment: I think you better have the if inside the while to avoid overflow of the int, and also conserve the - sing to multiply by it before check. Also check if he char is a digit.

Comment: why not just use strtol ?

Comment: The question is obviously very poorly specified, so I did my best with the information the poster provided.  I am well aware of the pitfalls in this implementation.